# AngularJS FullCalendar get events by ID

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

Im trying to get calendar events from mysql db using fullcalendar, PHP and angularjs.

HTTP

```
<div ng-controller="calController" ng-show="tab4">
    <div id="calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar">
    </div>
</div>
```

My conroller:

```
.controller('calController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', 'uiCalendarConfig', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, uiCalendarConfig) {

var user = $rootScope.userID;

$scope.eventSources = {
    url: 'php/events.php?agentID=' + user
};

$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar: {
        height: 300,
        editable: false,
        allDay: false,
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'agendaWeek prev,next'
        }
    }
};}]);
```

My PHP:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `Events`";$sql = $con->prepare($sql);$sql->execute();$results=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $json=json_encode($results);
```

Im getting the results into my calendar but they all the results in the DB. Probably because the statemnt is `select * from events...`

In the controller you can see im passing the URL with my parameter "user" but this has no effect on the return of the php script.

So my question is how do I return only a specific users events and not all the events?

I guess my PHP file needs to be edited but I dont know what to do..

**EDIT:**

Ive also tried getting the events into an array and then binding to eventSources:

```
var user = $rootScope.userID;

var events = [];

$scope.eventSources = [events];

$http.post('php/events.php', {
    'user': user
}).success(function (data) {

    console.log(data);

    angular.forEach(data, function (value) {

        events.push({
            start: value.start,
            end: value.end
        });
    });

    console.log("events", events);
    console.log("sources", $scope.eventSources);

});
```

This works well to get events using an ID but now I don't see the events in the calendar.

```
console.log("events", events);
console.log("sources", $scope.eventSources);
```

The output for the above is:

[image]

Why wouldnt events be showing up in the calendar with an array? Any help would be amazing.

Thanks

Comment: Wrap off quotes form table name instead use backtick

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of troubleshooting i found that the PHP script needed to be called once the calendar was loaded.

Once I did this I was able to see the events in the calendar:

```
.controller('calController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', 'uiCalendarConfig', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, uiCalendarConfig) {

var user = $rootScope.userID;
var isFirstTime = true;
var events = [];

$scope.getEvents = function () {
    $http.post('php/events.php', {
        'user': user
    }).success(function (data) {
        //events = data;
        angular.forEach(data, function (value) {
            events.push({
                start: value.start,
                end: value.end
            });
        });

    });
}

$scope.eventSources = [events];

$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar: {
        height: 300,
        editable: false,
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay prev,next'
        },
        eventAfterAllRender: function () {
            if ($scope.eventSources.length > 0 && isFirstTime) {
                isFirstTime = false;
                $scope.getEvents();
            }

        }
    }
};}]);
```